# O identificador de varias partes "System.Data.DataRowView" não pode ser associada

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-select, ado.net

try
                {

```
                if (cmbFavorecido.SelectedValue != null )
                {

                    txtID.Text = cmbFavorecido.SelectedValue.ToString();

                    cn = conexao.ConectarSqlServer();
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CNPJ_FORNECEDOR FROM FORNECEDOR WHERE ID_FORNECEDOR =  " + txtID.Text, cn);
                    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ad.Fill(ds, "TbFornecedor");
                    txtCnpj.Text = ds.Tables["TbFornecedor"].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

                }
```

Comment: Poste o código, imagem não é recomendada neste caso.

Comment: Como o @rubStackOverflow já disse, não coloque uma imagem do seu código. Clique em [edit] e poste o código propriamente dito. Aliás, dê uma olhada em [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verifícavel](/help/mcve) e [ask] *=)*.

Comment: Pronto, postei o codigo, se puder me ajudar serei grato.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma.

```
 if (cmbFavorecido.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = myConnString;
                try
                {
                    String txtID = cmbFavorecido.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    txtID.Text = txtID;

                    //cn = conexao.ConectarSqlServer();
                    //cn.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "select CNPJ_FORNECEDOR FROM FORNECEDOR WHERE ID_FORNECEDOR = @txtID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtID", txtID);

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    conn.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    txtCnpj.Text = dt.Rows[0][0];

                }
                catch (SqlException sqle)
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
```

A uma coisa importante em seu código que você precisa ter cuidado, que é a passagem de parametros. Da forma que você esta fazendo você corre o risco de alguém usar [Injeção SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL), por isso user sempre `Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtID", txtID);` para passar parâmetros.

Assim os tipos dos parâmetros são adequados aos tipos das colunas e a instrução SQL fica por conta do ADO.NET.
Além disso, uma boa prática é efetuar validações.

Comment: Marconcillio Souza, quando vou executa o código,na linha onde tem o "ad.fill(dt); da o seguinte erro com a mensagem   :                                "Fill: Propriedade SelectCommand.Connection não foi inicializada."

Comment: Veja agora .... faltou passa sua string de conexão .

Comment: Cara tive que mudar o nome da variavel txtID pois estava dando conflito com o nome da TextBox, no ad.SelectCommand foi atribuido  o cmd (objeto do sqlcommand) , na hora de pedi pra exigir no TextBox acrescentei o .toString();                                                                                          só que ainda continua dando erro no ad.fill(dt) dessa vez com a seguinte mensagem "Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto System.Windows.Forms.TextBox para um provedor gerenciado de tipo nativo"    cara desde já agradeço por essa ajuda